# Extract a column from a matrix (list of lists) in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

For an input like `extract_column([[1,2], [3, 4], [5,6]], 0, X).`, I'd like to see the result as `[1,3,5]`. I'm not sure if my base case is correct or how to proceed with the recursive logic.

The point is to get the *Ith* element of the header (list), append it to the result list *R* and recursively apply that logic to all of the lists inside the big list.

```
extract_column([], [R1]).
extract_column([H|T], I, [R]) :-
   extract_column([T], I, [R1]),
   nth0(I, [H], num1),
   append([R], num1, R1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the base case is not correct and furthermore there is no need to use `append/3`.

- The base case should define a predicate of arity 3 (i.e., with arguments *Matrix*, *Index*, *Column*).
- To add an element `Y` to the beginning of a list `Ys`, just write `[Y|Ys]`.
- For more efficiency, it's better to use tail recursion (moving the recursive call to the end of the clause).

Thus, a possible solution is:

```
extract_column([], _, []).
extract_column([X|Xs], I, [Y|Ys]) :-
    nth0(I, X, Y),
    extract_column(Xs, I, Ys).
```

Examples:

```
?- extract_column( [[1,2], [3, 4], [5,6]], 0, Col).
Col = [1, 3, 5].

?- extract_column( [[1,2], [3, 4], [5,6]], I, Col).
I = 0,
Col = [1, 3, 5] ;
I = 1,
Col= [2, 4, 6].
```